# Using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word, flesch-kincaid

I'm attempting to leverage the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word dll in my asp.net application.  Long story short, an internal web based document management/editing system requires access to a MS Word flesch-kincaid value on an ad-hoc basis.  I have no problem using this dll in a console app, but I can't get the right permissions to it when accessed via asp.net.

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

I've tried everything in [this forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfx64bit/thread/65a355ce-49c1-47f1-8c12-d9cf5f23c53e) with no luck. I'm using .Net 4.0 on Win7, I've tried both 32 and 64 bit versions of MS Word.  I'm also anticipating more head-aches once I deploy to our server running Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757 Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the openXML SDK instead for the reason todda.speot.is gives

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5124

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/87711/Manipulate-Docx-with-C-without-Microsoft-Word-inst

Comment: This is not what the OP needs. He is not asking about creating or manipulating word documents but he needs a function (calculate the flesch-kincaid score of a text) from word itself. What he needs however (word in a server environment) is unfortunately not supported and known to cause all sorts of problems

Comment: Actually this is not a problem editing it on a server as long as you don't use microsoft word which is exactly what the link is for. This does solve the problem of needing to change a word document on a server

Comment: Again: It's not about editing a document. It's about the functionality in the msword dll to calculate a flesh-kincaid score for a document. If you think this can be done with the openXml SDK please be more specific in your answer and show us how